# How to change the order of html elements inside ReactJS return function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object generated from an API and the values of the object are rendered inside the return function of ReactJS. I'm trying to render these items as per the order which it is appears inside the object. For example if I have an object that contains a video url, a title and a genre. As of now the return function renders the embed url first then the title and then the genre. I'm expecting this rendering order should change dynamically (Or conditionally) as the order of the array changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var content_obj = {
                    "content": [
                                {
                                  "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Glc2mHLPRM",
                                  "type":"video"
                                }
                               ]
                    "genre":"drama", 
                    "title":"My Video"   
                    };

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <ReactPlayer url={content_obj.content[0]['url']} playing controls />
              <div className="second">{content_obj.title}</div>
              <div className="third">{content_obj.genre}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

That means if I change(Or api changed) the `content_obj` order from above to

```
var content_obj = {
                    "content": [
                                {
                                 "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Glc2mHLPRM",
                                 "type":"video"
                                }
                               ], 
                    "title":"My Video",
                    "genre":"drama"
                    };
```

Then the html should be rendered as first embed url then title and then genre.

Comment: `content_array.reverse();`

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela content_array can have more than two items and the order could be changed at any degree

Comment: I think the only way to do this is `.sort()` with a comparator and hardcoded string names. A bit more detail about the overall use-case would be helpful. Do you have control over `content_array`, or is that coming from props? If it is coming through props, do you have control over the parent component and will the ordering be the only thing that changes, or will there be arbitrary content? Likely, the design can be improved to avoid a hacky solution.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen Idont have control over the array .. array is coming as an object from an api. I made it as an array in order to simplify and generalize the question

Comment: I'd try to use regex to check if `content_array[0]` is a URL and then display the `div` or `ReactPlayer` first accordingly.

Comment: @Maria that's one way to approach but in real world use of this component the object/array may be large and different type of data might be there. I simplified and generalized the question for better explanation.

Comment: So the contents (URL, etc) will change arbitrarily? If so, what grounds do you have to sort based on? Can you provide more examples of the `content` array? I think a lot is lost in the simplification here. I mean, you only show two child components that need to be sorting, so are you planning on dynamically generating `n` components? Feels a bit like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @LalasM you can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then in the map function check what kind of data it is and return the appropriate html.

Comment: @Maria the problem with that, though, is that the component needs to know something about the array ahead of time, like the specific strings, for example, which sounds impossible. We need some requirement like "if the string at index `i` in the array matches a URL, it should be moved to the front" or something along those lines. Without that, I don't see what can be done.

Comment: @LalasM in your update, you have an invalid `content` array that has key-values. What's going on here?

Comment: @ggorlen that was a typo .. that content is an array of object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a half coded half plain text example of how I think you could approach the problem.

Using array.map would allow you to return the html for each array item in order though as you stated in the comments you will need to come up with some logic to test each string in the array in order to return the correct code. For URL's you could for sure do this with regex, I don't know what other options you need to support.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var content_array = an array filled with different types of strings?

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
              {content_array.map(content => {
                if(use regex to check if content is a url){
                  return <ReactPlayer url={content} playing controls />
                } else if(some other condition to check its text){
                  return <div className="second">{content}</div>
                } else if (whatever other conditions you have){
                  return other stuff
                }
              });}


            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the instructions from comments and request for more clarification i have edited the question .. but still this is more likely answeres the query .. thanks @maria